# Array.length & ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, minecraft, bukkit

I excluded a large portion of the code that was irrelevant to the issue. Below is the code for a Bukkit plugin -- everything below is defined. However, when the code attempts to go through the second if statement (where I attempt to compare the length), it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I have compared `exempt.length` to `0` and printed the result, which gave `true`, so I'm not sure why the comparison is producing an error.

```
public Player[] exempt = { }; // If exempt is defined as a new Player[100], it will result in NullPointerException.

if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("toggle")) {
    boolean isExempt = false;

    if (exempt.length > 0) {
        for (Player player : exempt) {
            if (player.getName().equals(commandSender.getName())) {
                isExempt = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isExempt) {
        exempt[exempt.length] = (Player) commandSender; // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    }

    commandSender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Toggled receiving AdminChat to " + (!isExempt ? "true" : "false") + ".");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You are sure that it is that line?

Comment: `exempt[exempt.length]` - that is never valid.

Comment: `exempt[exempt.length]` will by definition fail. The indexes of an array are numbered `0` to `length-1`, so `length` is too large. --- Unlike some other languages, Java arrays cannot resize, so it won't grow by using that construct. To get a resizable array, use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `exempt[exempt.length].`

Since indices are allocated from 0 to exempt.length-1.

What's more, that line should also be inside the "if (exempt.length > 0)" block, as it will give an exception too when the array is empty. Because exempt.length == 0, but exempt.length == -1

Thanks for Aimert's suggestion.

Comment: That line should also be inside the "if (exempt.length > 0)" block, as it will give an exception too when the array is empty.

Comment: @Aimert Alright, I understand my mistake, partly due to both of you. When I define it as `public Player[] exempt = new Player[100];`, 100 being example, it then changes to a NullPointerException.

Comment: It means 100 elements. There will not be an element with index 100.

Comment: Because you have allocated the memory space, but not fill in the address of the object it points to. Hence, this leads to NullPointerException. Please initialize every element as a new Player or point to some already existing Player.

Comment: Where are you getting the NullPointerException?

Comment: @Tipton So, even if the memory is allocated, I wouldn't be able to compare the length?

Comment: You can of course get the length of array as 100. However, please note that you are iterating every element in the array in your loop. If you do not init the object, how can you use the method getName()?

Comment: Can't you use a list instead of an array? It would be way easier to use the size() method and filling the data.

Comment: @Aimert I'm trying that now, yeah, because I would need to resize it.

Comment: To enhance your program evolvability, you should use a dynamic array like list as the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

So rather than using an array, I went with a list, as suggested.

`List<Player> exempt = new ArrayList<Player>;`

And after correcting all the code (updating it from Array to ArrayList methods and etcetera), it worked like a charm.